# Why does the right side coordinate does not appear?

Tags: qgis, coordinates, grids-graticules

I was working on QGIS 3.28 and the CRS is WGS 1984 Web Mercator. Apparently my right side coordinate doesn't appear in scale 1:750.000.

[image]

But it appears when I change the scale to 1:2.000.000 or above.

[image]

How do I get the coordinates appears on scale 1:750.000?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue using QGIS 3.28.0. All the labels from all directions appear as expected. Try to create another new layout from scratch and check again if the same issue apprears.

Comment: I have this very same issue on all the recent (2022) QGIS versions. I don't know before, I was not using layout/grids. From what I experienced, it seems to be related to how far the next mark is close from the right order. To work around the issue, either I use zoom/framing/longitude steps so that there is a mark close to the right side (inside the frame). Sometimes just extending the map frame a bit and moving it around makes the mark appear.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your map main properties under the map layout,under 'CRS'make sure you change it according to the CRS you first choose under grid Appearance ( Grid type, CRS, Interval)... Hope this will help solve your problem